# GoogleCloudStorageToBigQueryOperator fail in airflow

Tags: airflow

I'm trying to move data from the SQL server to google bigquery.
Because there is no direct way to do it, I first move the data from SQL server to the GCP bucket with MSSQLToGCSOperator
and then from the bucket to bigquery with GCSToBigQueryOperator
.but for some reason my GCSToBigQueryOperator is failing

here is my code:
`

```
"""
Code that goes along with the Airflow located at:
http://airflow.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorial.html
"""
import json
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.contrib.operators.gcs_to_bq import GoogleCloudStorageToBigQueryOperator
from airflow.providers.google.cloud.transfers.mssql_to_gcs import MSSQLToGCSOperator
from datetime import date
from airflow.providers.google.cloud.transfers.gcs_to_bigquery import GCSToBigQueryOperator
default_args = {
    "owner": "airflow",
    "depends_on_past": False,
    "start_date": datetime(2015, 6, 1),
    "email": ["airflow@airflow.com"],
    "email_on_failure": False,
    "email_on_retry": False,
    "retries": 1,
    "retry_delay": timedelta(minutes=5)

}

today = date.today()

dag = DAG("mrr_dim", default_args=default_args, schedule_interval=timedelta(1))

# start = BashOperator(
#     task_id='start',
#     bash_command='echo start',
#     dag=dag,
# )
#
# end = BashOperator(
#     task_id='end',
#     bash_command='echo end',
#     dag=dag,
# )

with open('/home/igor/airflow/dags/mrr_dim_querys.json', 'r') as file:
    table_json = json.load(file)

for index, query in enumerate(table_json):
    export_customers = MSSQLToGCSOperator(
        task_id=f'query_' + query['table'],
        sql=query['query'],
        bucket='igor_airflow_dev',
        filename=query['table'],
        schema_filename=f'schemas_{query["table"]}/export_{str(today)}_{query["table"]}.json',
        mssql_conn_id='mssql_default',
        gcp_conn_id='google_cloud_default',
        export_format='json',
        field_delimiter=',',
        dag=dag
    )
    load_to_bq = GCSToBigQueryOperator(
        task_id=f'load_to_bq_' + query['table'],
        bucket='igor_airflow_dev',
        source_objects=[query['table']],
        destination_project_dataset_table=f'igordwh.MRR.{query["table"]}',
        schema_object=f'schemas_{query["table"]}/export_{str(today)}_{query["table"]}.json',
        source_format='NEWLINE_DELIMITED_JSON',
        create_disposition='CREATE_IF_NEEDED',
        write_disposition='WRITE_TRUNCATE',
        gcp_conn_id= 'google_cloud_default',

        dag=dag
    )


    export_customers >> load_to_bq
```

`

here is my log:
`

```
*** Reading local file: /home/igor/airflow/logs/dag_id=mrr_dim/run_id=manual__2022-11-23T10:24:43.123218+00:00/task_id=load_to_bq_MRR_Customers/attempt=1.log
[2022-11-23, 10:25:12 UTC] {taskinstance.py:1171} INFO - Dependencies all met for <TaskInstance: mrr_dim.load_to_bq_MRR_Customers manual__2022-11-23T10:24:43.123218+00:00 [queued]>
[2022-11-23, 10:25:12 UTC] {taskinstance.py:1171} INFO - Dependencies all met for <TaskInstance: mrr_dim.load_to_bq_MRR_Customers manual__2022-11-23T10:24:43.123218+00:00 [queued]>
[2022-11-23, 10:25:12 UTC] {taskinstance.py:1368} INFO - 
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[2022-11-23, 10:25:12 UTC] {taskinstance.py:1369} INFO - Starting attempt 1 of 2
[2022-11-23, 10:25:12 UTC] {taskinstance.py:1370} INFO - 
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[2022-11-23, 10:25:12 UTC] {taskinstance.py:1389} INFO - Executing <Task(GCSToBigQueryOperator): load_to_bq_MRR_Customers> on 2022-11-23 10:24:43.123218+00:00
[2022-11-23, 10:25:12 UTC] {standard_task_runner.py:52} INFO - Started process 11814 to run task
[2022-11-23, 10:25:12 UTC] {standard_task_runner.py:79} INFO - Running: ['airflow', 'tasks', 'run', 'mrr_dim', 'load_to_bq_MRR_Customers', 'manual__2022-11-23T10:24:43.123218+00:00', '--job-id', '25602', '--raw', '--subdir', 'DAGS_FOLDER/mrr_dim.py', '--cfg-path', '/tmp/tmpv7uzw8jc', '--error-file', '/tmp/tmpfsze26wu']
[2022-11-23, 10:25:12 UTC] {standard_task_runner.py:80} INFO - Job 25602: Subtask load_to_bq_MRR_Customers
[2022-11-23, 10:25:12 UTC] {task_command.py:371} INFO - Running <TaskInstance: mrr_dim.load_to_bq_MRR_Customers manual__2022-11-23T10:24:43.123218+00:00 [running]> on host igor-VirtualBox
[2022-11-23, 10:25:12 UTC] {taskinstance.py:1581} INFO - Exporting the following env vars:
AIRFLOW_CTX_DAG_EMAIL=airflow@airflow.com
AIRFLOW_CTX_DAG_OWNER=airflow
AIRFLOW_CTX_DAG_ID=mrr_dim
AIRFLOW_CTX_TASK_ID=load_to_bq_MRR_Customers
AIRFLOW_CTX_EXECUTION_DATE=2022-11-23T10:24:43.123218+00:00
AIRFLOW_CTX_TRY_NUMBER=1
AIRFLOW_CTX_DAG_RUN_ID=manual__2022-11-23T10:24:43.123218+00:00
[2022-11-23, 10:25:12 UTC] {base.py:68} INFO - Using connection ID 'google_cloud_default' for task execution.
[2022-11-23, 10:25:12 UTC] {base.py:68} INFO - Using connection ID 'google_cloud_default' for task execution.
[2022-11-23, 10:25:13 UTC] {gcs_to_bigquery.py:320} INFO - Autodetected fields from schema object: [{'mode': 'NULLABLE', 'name': 'CustomerID', 'type': 'INTEGER'}, {'mode': 'NULLABLE', 'name': 'PersonID', 'type': 'INTEGER'}, {'mode': 'NULLABLE', 'name': 'StoreID', 'type': 'INTEGER'}, {'mode': 'NULLABLE', 'name': 'TerritoryID', 'type': 'INTEGER'}, {'mode': 'NULLABLE', 'name': 'AccountNumber', 'type': 'STRING'}, {'mode': 'NULLABLE', 'name': 'rowguid', 'type': 'STRING'}, {'mode': 'NULLABLE', 'name': 'ModifiedDate', 'type': 'TIMESTAMP'}]
[2022-11-23, 10:25:13 UTC] {gcs_to_bigquery.py:367} INFO - Using existing BigQuery table for storing data...
[2022-11-23, 10:25:13 UTC] {base.py:68} INFO - Using connection ID 'google_cloud_default' for task execution.
[2022-11-23, 10:25:15 UTC] {gcs_to_bigquery.py:397} INFO - Executing: {'load': {'autodetect': True, 'createDisposition': 'CREATE_IF_NEEDED', 'destinationTable': {'projectId': 'igordwh', 'datasetId': 'MRR', 'tableId': 'MRR_Customers'}, 'destinationTableProperties': {'description': None, 'labels': None}, 'sourceFormat': 'NEWLINE_DELIMITED_JSON', 'skipLeadingRows': 1, 'sourceUris': ['gs://igor_airflow_dev/MRR_Customers'], 'writeDisposition': 'WRITE_TRUNCATE', 'ignoreUnknownValues': False, 'allowQuotedNewlines': False, 'encoding': 'UTF-8', 'schema': {'fields': [{'name': '{"AccountNumber": "AW00000001"', 'type': 'STRING', 'mode': 'NULLABLE'}, {'name': ' "CustomerID": 1', 'type': 'STRING', 'mode': 'NULLABLE'}, {'name': ' "ModifiedDate": "2014-09-12T11:15:07.263000"', 'type': 'STRING', 'mode': 'NULLABLE'}, {'name': ' "PersonID": null', 'type': 'STRING', 'mode': 'NULLABLE'}, {'name': ' "StoreID": 934', 'type': 'STRING', 'mode': 'NULLABLE'}, {'name': ' "TerritoryID": 1', 'type': 'STRING', 'mode': 'NULLABLE'}, {'name': ' "rowguid": "3F5AE95E-B87D-4AED-95B4-C3797AFCB74F"}', 'type': 'STRING', 'mode': 'NULLABLE'}]}}}
[2022-11-23, 10:25:15 UTC] {bigquery.py:1539} INFO - Inserting job airflow_mrr_dim_load_to_bq_MRR_Customers_2022_11_23T10_24_43_123218_00_00_4c61890238ddb6f919626c6dad25cb87
[2022-11-23, 10:25:16 UTC] {taskinstance.py:1902} ERROR - Task failed with exception
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/airflow/providers/google/cloud/transfers/gcs_to_bigquery.py", line 398, in execute
    job = self._submit_job(self.hook, job_id)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/airflow/providers/google/cloud/transfers/gcs_to_bigquery.py", line 276, in _submit_job
    return hook.insert_job(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/airflow/providers/google/common/hooks/base_google.py", line 462, in inner_wrapper
    return func(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/airflow/providers/google/cloud/hooks/bigquery.py", line 1542, in insert_job
    job._begin()
  File "/home/igor/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/google/cloud/bigquery/job/base.py", line 510, in _begin
    api_response = client._call_api(
  File "/home/igor/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/google/cloud/bigquery/client.py", line 782, in _call_api
    return call()
  File "/home/igor/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/google/api_core/retry.py", line 283, in retry_wrapped_func
    return retry_target(
  File "/home/igor/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/google/api_core/retry.py", line 190, in retry_target
    return target()
  File "/home/igor/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/google/cloud/_http/__init__.py", line 494, in api_request
    raise exceptions.from_http_response(response)
google.api_core.exceptions.BadRequest: 400 POST https://bigquery.googleapis.com/bigquery/v2/projects/igordwh/jobs?prettyPrint=false: Invalid field name "{"AccountNumber": "AW00000001"". Fields must contain only letters, numbers, and underscores, start with a letter or underscore, and be at most 300 characters long.
[2022-11-23, 10:25:16 UTC] {taskinstance.py:1407} INFO - Marking task as UP_FOR_RETRY. dag_id=mrr_dim, task_id=load_to_bq_MRR_Customers, execution_date=20221123T102443, start_date=20221123T102512, end_date=20221123T102516
[2022-11-23, 10:25:16 UTC] {standard_task_runner.py:92} ERROR - Failed to execute job 25602 for task load_to_bq_MRR_Customers (400 POST https://bigquery.googleapis.com/bigquery/v2/projects/igordwh/jobs?prettyPrint=false: Invalid field name "{"AccountNumber": "AW00000001"". Fields must contain only letters, numbers, and underscores, start with a letter or underscore, and be at most 300 characters long.; 11814)
[2022-11-23, 10:25:16 UTC] {local_task_job.py:156} INFO - Task exited with return code 1
[2022-11-23, 10:25:16 UTC] {local_task_job.py:279} INFO - 0 downstream tasks scheduled from follow-on schedule check
```

`

Comment: did you check the json file if it's correctly formatted. Seems weird that there are two double quotes at the end: `"{"AccountNumber": "AW00000001""`

Answer (score 3):

Your first task should be using `export_format='ndjson'` instead of `export_format='json'`. This will format the file so that the GSCToBigQueryOperator can read interpret it properly.

```
export_customers = MSSQLToGCSOperator(
            task_id=f'query_' + query['table'],
            sql=query['query'],
            bucket='igor_airflow_dev',
            filename=query['table'],
            schema_filename=f'schemas_{query["table"]}/export_{str(today)}_{query["table"]}.json',
            mssql_conn_id='mssql_default',
            gcp_conn_id='google_cloud_default',
            export_format='ndjson',
            field_delimiter=',',
            dag=dag
        )
```

One other note, if you are using apache-airflow-providers-google==8.5.0, the most recent changes caused it to have issues reading ndjson files. If you revert your version to 8.3.0 it should work. (I was dealing with this issue the past two days after updating cloud composer/airflow from 2.0.2-2.1.4 --> 2.1.2-2.3.4.